# Can't compile using MinGW, Eclipse and Boost (1.50.0)

Tags: eclipse, gcc, boost, linker, mingw

I'm using MinGW, Eclipse and Boost for some TCP/IP programming. Normally I use Visual Studio, but for this project I'm using Eclipse and MinGW. I have runned the header test program and that runs fine.

When I want to build a project with `asio` included, I'm getting reference errors.

Under the settings of MinGW in Eclipse I have included the library and under C++ I have added the include search path. The libraries are built statically.

I have read online that I also need to include the compiler flag `-lws2_32`. I have done this in Eclipse under the MinGW settings in the miscellaneous.

I include `asio` the following way:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

The error that I get is the following:

```
undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

With kind regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libws2_32.a` is obviously not linked properly. I suspect that adding linkage switch (such as `-l`) to miscellaneous is wrong way of doing this. From what I remember, in **Paths and Symbols** section there is **Libraries** tab where you can simply add `ws2_32` (without any flags) and let Eclipse do its job of invoking GCC with appropriate switches.

Comment: Thanks i think that your suggestion sovled it! Now just need to add the system lib from boost since there is i get the following error: boost::system::system_category(). I'm gonna do that now keep you posted. Thanks again!

Comment: Just added the system, ecexption and signals libries. And got no errors. I still have some warnings (-wall flag is on) that has to do with the winsock i think. #warning Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target),  #warning For example, add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line,  #warning Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately.How do i solve this?

Comment: Well, just do what it says, add `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` into definitions.

Comment: Maby a very stupid question but where do i add this deffinition in eclipse?

Comment: It was some tab in **Paths and Symbols** once again, just look carefully.

Comment: Thanks! I put the _WIN32_WINNT under symbols and the warning was gone.